# convert mongodb $reduce code to spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mongodb, spring-mongo

I need to covert below code into spring-boot mongodb api.

```
instName : {$reduce: { 
        input : { $setUnion: "$accounts.instName"}, 
        initialValue: "", 
        in: { $concat : ["$$value", "$$this", ", "] }}}
```

I have tried

```
 ArrayOperators.arrayOf(SetOperators.SetUnion.arrayAsSet("accounts.institutionDetails.instName")).reduce(StringOperators.valueOf("$$value").concat("$$this").concat(", ")).startingWith("")
```

Getting below error

```
org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property $$value found for type Application!
```

Any help is appropriated.

Answer (score -1):

```
ArrayOperators.ConcatArrays.arrayOf("$$this").concat("$$value")
```